# Adding button in Drawer after the listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm using a Navigation Drawer in my application which contain a ListView to show some data.I have done this using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout lib.Now i want to add one button below the ListView Contain by Drawer.How it can be done?

my .xml is............................................

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#990033" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_titlebar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffcc"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbtnDrawer"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_menu"
                android:contentDescription="@string/vegetables" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbtnLabel"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image2"
                android:contentDescription="@string/vegetables" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblLabel"
                android:layout_width="225dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="@string/vegetables"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbtnCart"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:background="@drawable/imgcart"
                android:contentDescription="@string/vegetables" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/lstShowVege"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstDrawerIn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#990033" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstDrawerCart"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#990033"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Buy"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

/**.................................................................................................................................................................I need button below the lstDrawerCart..........who represent Right drawer in my App.......But simply adding xml code for button here not allowing me to represent button in drawer it simply come as MainActivity View. Also i'm handling both left and Right drawer so if i need to wrap it in layout how i can do it.........................................................................................................................................*/

public class VegetablesActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,OnClickListener {

```
ListView lstDrawerIn,lstDrawerCart,lstShowVege;
String[] strTrailShow;
ImageButton imgbtnDrawer,imgbtnCart;
Intent intent;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
ArrayList<String> arr_stringDisplay=new ArrayList<String>();
DBHelper dbHelper;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// products JSONArray
JSONArray message = null;
//JSONObject 
JSONObject json;
//JSONParser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
//ArrayList to carry HashMap
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsListcart;

// url to get all products list
private static String url= "http://10.0.2.2/grocery/get_all_vegetables.php";
private static String url_getCart= "http://10.0.2.2/grocery/get_all_cartprod.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_VEGETABLE_ID = "vegetable_id";
private static final String TAG_VEGETABLE_NAME = "vegetable_name";
private static final String TAG_VEGETABLE_PRICE = "vegetable_price";
private static final String TAG_VEGETABLE_IMAGE = "vegetable_image";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "product_quantity";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE = "product_image";

//Arranging data to pass to the custom drawer to set in listview
String[] strDrawerIn;
private int[] image={R.drawable.facebook,R.drawable.facebook,R.drawable.facebook,R.drawable.facebook,R.drawable.facebook,R.drawable.facebook};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vegetables);

    dbHelper=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    lstDrawerIn=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstDrawerIn);
    lstDrawerCart=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDrawerCart);
    lstShowVege=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstShowVege);
    strDrawerIn=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strDrawerIn);
    strTrailShow=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strTrailShow);
    imgbtnDrawer=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtnDrawer);
    imgbtnCart=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnCart);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    productsListcart = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

/*  initialising the String array variable from resources. 
  * calling custom adapter constructer by passing "Initialise string array","image array","textView which show design of one row","context".
  * Finally put listener on listviw on which this custom adapter seted.
*/  strDrawerIn=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strDrawerIn);
    myAdapter=new MyAdapter(strDrawerIn,image,this);
    lstDrawerIn.setAdapter(myAdapter);      
    lstDrawerIn.setOnItemClickListener(this);   

    lstShowVege.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VEGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button btnAddCart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
            btnAddCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button VEGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }
    });

    //Using onclickListener on imgbuttons
    imgbtnDrawer.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgbtnCart.setOnClickListener(this);

    checkconnection();

}//OnCreate close

private void refresh() {
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
}

private void refreshCart() {
    new LoadCart().execute();
}

//Dialog to check Connection    
public void checkconnection()
{
    //checking connection of internet
    ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(HomeActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(nInfo!= null && nInfo.isConnected() ){
        //if connection present call background class
        refresh();
    }
    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(VegetablesActivity.this);
        builder1.setCancelable(false);

        LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
        builder1.setView(inflator.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checkconnection, null));

        builder1.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder1.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}

//coming here when clicked on ListView of Drawer that is, lstDrawerIn.
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long id) {
        selectitem(pos);
        switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;

        case 1:
            intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VegetablesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;

         case 2:
            intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FruitsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;

         case 3:
            intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DairyProductsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;

         case 4:
            intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;  

          default:
            break;
        }
 }
 //using to highlist the the selected item or textView From ListView of Drawer.
 public void selectitem(int pos) {
     lstDrawerIn.setItemChecked(pos, true);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgbtnDrawer:
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(lstDrawerIn))
            {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lstDrawerIn);
            }
            else
            {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(lstDrawerIn);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imgbtnCart:
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(R.id.lstDrawerCart))
            {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lstDrawerCart);
            }
            else
            {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(lstDrawerCart);
                refreshCart();
            }
            break;  

        default:
            break;
     }
 }

 /**
  * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 **/
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VegetablesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting string array containg output at each position from JSONParser.
         String[] st = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET", params);

         for (int j = 0; j < st.length; j++) {
            try {
                    //Converting Strings of each position of st into the JSONObject.
                    json = new JSONObject(st[j]);

                    if (!json.equals(null)) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        message =  json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = message.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String vegetable_id = c.getString(TAG_VEGETABLE_ID);
                            String vegetable_name = c.getString(TAG_VEGETABLE_NAME);
                            String vegetable_price = c.getString(TAG_VEGETABLE_PRICE);
                            String vegetable_image = c.getString(TAG_VEGETABLE_IMAGE);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_VEGETABLE_ID, vegetable_id);
                            map.put(TAG_VEGETABLE_NAME, vegetable_name);
                            map.put(TAG_VEGETABLE_PRICE, vegetable_price);
                            map.put(TAG_VEGETABLE_IMAGE, vegetable_image);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         } 
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
      protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView using custom Adapter
                 * */
                BackgroundAdapter adapter = new BackgroundAdapter(VegetablesActivity.this, productsList, TAG_VEGETABLE_NAME, TAG_VEGETABLE_PRICE, TAG_VEGETABLE_IMAGE);
                // updating listview
                lstShowVege.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
      }
}//background class close

/**
  * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 **/
class LoadCart extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VegetablesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Cart. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        productsListcart.clear();
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting string array containg output at each position from JSONParser.
         String[] st = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_getCart,"GET", params);

        for (int j = 0; j < st.length; j++) {
            try {
                    //Converting Strings of each position of st into the JSONObject.
                    json = new JSONObject(st[j]);

                    if (!json.equals(null)) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        message =  json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = message.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing each json item in variable
                                String product_id = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                                String product_name = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String product_price = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE);
                                String product_quantity = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY);
                                String product_image = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE);

                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, product_name);
                                map.put(TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE, product_price);
                                map.put(TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY, product_quantity);
                                map.put(TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE, product_image);

                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                productsListcart.add(map);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
             } 
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
          protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView using custom Adapter
                     * */
                    CartAdapter adapter = new CartAdapter(VegetablesActivity.this, productsListcart, TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE, TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY, TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE);
                    // updating listview
                    lstDrawerCart.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
            });
          }
    }//background LOADCART class close
}//main class close
```

Comment: Dude why don't you use `NavigationView`?

Comment: Please, allow me some more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout takes two views, first is the main content view and the second is the view drawn on drawer slide.

So I suggest to wrap all the views other than the main content in a layout and put it under the main content layout.

Edit:

As I understand you want to add a button under the listview of the right drawer, so you should wrap the listview with a button in a linear layout and don't forget to set the gravity of it to the right

Comment: means you saying i need to wrap my both the left and right drawer in a layout also i wrap button in the same layout?

Comment: I wrap my right drawer with a button into the layout but now i getting classcastException in java. it's saying..."android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams".............for line..drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(lstDrawerCart).

Comment: I get a solution, as per all comments i'm doing but when i opening a drawer in  java file i'm passing ListView only as parameter to openDrawer(). but now i create a Linearlayout object containing  my ListView and button and pass to that method. the problem is simple but out of mind.thanks any way.........